# Drupal core update from 7.56 to 7.59?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Before I have version 7.56 & now changed to 7.59, after files & folder replaced then to "status report" in admin section(admin/reports/status) version is changed to 7.59 & site is working fine. Now if I run update.php then which particular changes will be happen in database? Please advice.

Comment: What is the question? If you go to update.php it should tell you what is going to happen before it does the update

Comment: I have replace all core files & folder from old one. After run update.php anything change to DB?

Comment: It would have told you if there were updates to the DB before running update.php.

Comment: Is it necessary to run update.php when only drupal core need to be update?

Comment: when you run update.php, [HOOK_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) is run, drupal core, modules and I think also themes can implement this hook, so update.php should be run when updating any of these.